# React Link causes page reload when sidebar collapsed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a collapsible sidebar that contains li's that are React-Router Links to other pages in my single page application. When the sidebar is open all Links work correctly. However when the sidebar is collapsed the Links cause the new URL to be loaded rather than rendered onto the page.

When collapsed, links are accessible by hovering over nav headers.

```
<li className={ this.routeActive(['dashboard']) ? 'active' : '' }>
  <Link className="nav-item" to="/dashboard" title="Dashboard">
   <em className="icon-speedometer" aria-hidden="true"></em>
   <span data-localize="sidebar.nav.SINGLEVIEW"><Translate value="dashboard"/></span>
   </Link>
</li>
<li className={ this.routeActive(['products', 'products/new', 'customers', 'products/groups', 'products/categories', 'agents', 'vendors', 'paymentTerms', 'priceLevel']) ? 'active' : '' }>
   <div className="nav-item" onClick={ this.toggleItemCollapse.bind(this, 'generalInformation') }>
       <div className="pull-right label label-info">1</div>
       <em className="icon-book-open"></em>
       <span data-localize="sidebar.nav.MENU"><large><Translate value="general_information"/></large></span>
   </div>
   <Collapse in={ this.state.collapse.generalInformation } timeout={ 100 }>
       <ul id="products" className="nav sidebar-subnav">
           <li className="sidebar-subnav-header"><Translate value="general_information"/></li>
           <li className={ this.routeActive('products') ? 'active' : '' }>
               <Link to="/products" title="Products">
                    <span data-localize="sidebar.nav.PRODUCTS"><Translate value="product_management"/></span>
               </Link>
           </li>
```

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: When collapsed the Dashboard link still works correctly and renders the new page, but any other link causes the page to load again